# How to install Tridion Default Templates with Template Builder?

Tags: tridion

I want to install the Tridion 2011 Default Templates using the Template Builder.  I select Tools, Create Default Building Blocks, chose the folder, and select OK.  I have tried this on the server and locally with Template Builder.

It waits about 1 second and says success.  I see a new Folder 'Default Templates' in Tridion, but no Templates there.

I am really interested in the Default Finish Actions TBB.

Is there another way to install the Default TBBs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds little bit odd. Did you check if there is another folder under "Default Templates" and may be you imported there? What folder you selected when you're creating the Default Templates.

Check the following documentation to load only specific default templates:
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_66B5DBF6F598472AA30D61E947BC479A

Comment: That did it!  I upgraded directly from Tridion 5.3 SP1 to Tridion 2011 SP1.  The Tridion.ContentManager.config did not contain defaultTemplatesScripts.  I added the defaultTemplatesScripts section and also created the file SetupDefaultTemplates.xml.  Then used the Create Default Building Blocks in Template Builder and it worked perfectly!  Thanks!!